# Qt Mac Application Failed to Create Self-contained App Bundle (Qt Creator Build)

Tags: macos, qt, dyld, otool, macdeployqt

I'm using `Qt Creator 3.6.1` with `Qt 5.6.0 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit)`, and I encountered some problems while trying to create an app bundle for deployment.

*Note: the app name is called `bibi`*

1. `Qt Creator` successfully generated `bibi.app` under `build-bibi-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/` folder
2. This `bibi.app` failed to link Qt successfully on the other Mac
3. `macdeployqt` doesn't solve the problem

Followings are the details:

**Error screenshot when running `bibi.app` on the other Mac:**
[image]

**otool**

```
> otool -L build-bibi-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/bibi.app/Contents/MacOS/bibi
build-bibi-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_clang_64bit-Release/bibi.app/Contents/MacOS/bibi:
    @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

**macdeployqt**

```
> which macdeployqt
/Users/<myusername>/Qt/5.6/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt
> macdeployqt bibi.app
> otool -L bibi.app/Contents/MacOS/bibi
bibi.app/Contents/MacOS/bibi:
    @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

**tree bibi.app**

```
bibi.app
├── Contents
│   ├── Frameworks
│   │   ├── QtCore.framework
│   │   │   ├── QtCore -> Versions/Current/QtCore
│   │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
│   │   │   └── Versions
│   │   │       ├── 5
│   │   │       │   ├── QtCore
│   │   │       │   └── Resources
│   │   │       │       └── Info.plist
│   │   │       └── Current -> 5
│   │   ├── QtDBus.framework
│   │   │   ├── QtDBus -> Versions/Current/QtDBus
│   │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
│   │   │   └── Versions
│   │   │       ├── 5
│   │   │       │   ├── QtDBus
│   │   │       │   └── Resources
│   │   │       │       └── Info.plist
│   │   │       └── Current -> 5
│   │   ├── QtGui.framework
│   │   │   ├── QtGui -> Versions/Current/QtGui
│   │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
│   │   │   └── Versions
│   │   │       ├── 5
│   │   │       │   ├── QtGui
│   │   │       │   └── Resources
│   │   │       │       └── Info.plist
│   │   │       └── Current -> 5
│   │   ├── QtPrintSupport.framework
│   │   │   ├── QtPrintSupport -> Versions/Current/QtPrintSupport
│   │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
│   │   │   └── Versions
│   │   │       ├── 5
│   │   │       │   ├── QtPrintSupport
│   │   │       │   └── Resources
│   │   │       │       └── Info.plist
│   │   │       └── Current -> 5
│   │   └── QtWidgets.framework
│   │       ├── QtWidgets -> Versions/Current/QtWidgets
│   │       ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
│   │       └── Versions
│   │           ├── 5
│   │           │   ├── QtWidgets
│   │           │   └── Resources
│   │           │       └── Info.plist
│   │           └── Current -> 5
│   ├── Info.plist
│   ├── MacOS
│   │   └── bibi
│   ├── PkgInfo
│   ├── PlugIns
│   │   ├── imageformats
│   │   │   ├── libqdds.dylib
│   │   │   ├── libqgif.dylib
│   │   │   ├── libqicns.dylib
│   │   │   ├── libqico.dylib
│   │   │   ├── libqjpeg.dylib
│   │   │   ├── libqtga.dylib
│   │   │   ├── libqtiff.dylib
│   │   │   ├── libqwbmp.dylib
│   │   │   └── libqwebp.dylib
│   │   ├── platforms
│   │   │   └── libqcocoa.dylib
│   │   └── printsupport
│   │       └── libcocoaprintersupport.dylib
│   └── Resources
│       ├── empty.lproj
│       └── qt.conf
└── Icon\r

38 directories, 32 files
```

Thanks.

### Problem Solved

Thanks scottt, and the problem is solved. Here are the reasons I failed to create self-contained app bundle successfully:

- `otool -L` didn't resolve @rpath, and I was confused since it always returned me the same output
- lack of a way to test if the bundle is already self-containing all the frameworks

In short, the problem can be solve by using Scott's `otool-rpath`, `lsof`, or setting `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` and `DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE`. And, I've written a note with details [here](http://note.heron.me/2016/05/qt-mac-application-failed-to-create.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you used the [qt-unified-max-x64-online.dmg](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-mac-x64-online.dmg) installer and installed Qt into `$HOME/Qt`. You can build your project with:

```
cd MY-QT-PROJECT
QT_BIN_DIR=$HOME/Qt/5.6/clang_64/bin
make clean
$QT_BIN_DIR/qmake -config release
make -j$(getconf NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
```

This creates an app bundle but it would *NOT* run on regular users' machines.

Look at the RPATH in the Mach-O executable buried in the bundle:

```
otool-rpath ./*.app/Contents/MacOS/*
/Users/user/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib
```

I'm using a small [otool-rpath](https://github.com/scottt/scottt-bin/blob/master/otool-rpath) script I wrote myself here for illustrative purposes.

That RPATH plus the install names listed in your `otool -L` output above make the dynamic linker, `dyld`, look for Qt frameworks under `/Users/user/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib`. Thus, it would *NOT* work for users who haven't installed Qt in the same location.

To change that, run Qt’s `macdeployqt` tool:

```
$QT_BIN_DIR/macdeployqt ./*.app -verbose=3 -always-overwrite -appstore-compliant
```

See an example `macdeployqt` log [here](https://gist.github.com/scottt/1d5a12788de97ea93255d25a0c14080e#file-macdeployqt-log).

`macdeployqt` creates self-contained app bundles. Observe how the RPATH in the executable changed from `/Users/user/Qt/5.6/clang_64/lib` to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`:

```
otool-rpath ./*.app/Contents/MacOS/*
@executable_path/../Frameworks
```

`@executable_path` does the obvious thing and is expanded by `dyld` to `bibi.app/Contents/MacOS` at run time. The RPATH in the executable and the install names together make dynamic linking within the bundle work at run time.

## Further Reading

- You can get a log of how the dynamic linker looks up libraries by setting `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` and `DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE`. [Example log](https://gist.github.com/scottt/1d5a12788de97ea93255d25a0c14080e#file-dyld-log). See [dyld(1)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/dyld/).
- You can use `lsof -p $PID | grep QtCore` to inspect which copy of the framework is actually used by your app at run-time. [Example log](https://gist.github.com/scottt/1d5a12788de97ea93255d25a0c14080e#file-lsof-out).
- [Run-Path Dependent Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html)
- [@executable path, @load path and @rpath](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath)

## References

- [Mac Developer Library: Mach-O Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/executing_files.html)
- [OSX ABI Mach-O File Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/)

Keywords: "**RPATH**", "**INSTALL NAME**", "**Mach-O dynamic linking**".

Note that **RPATH** in ELF has subtlely different semantics.